# next js: how to run chain middlware functions from a single file?

Tags: next.js, middleware

The next js docs detail how to create middleware on page calls.

```
Then, create a _middleware.ts file under your /pages directory.

Finally, export a middleware function from the _middleware.ts file.

// pages/_middleware.ts

import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  return new Response('Hello, world!')
}
```

how do we chain multiple middleware functions at a specifc level in page hierarchy?

Or is this designed so that each level has one middleware file and function?

Comment: You can only have one file/function per level, but nothing stops you from adding several function calls inside it. What's your specific use-case?

Comment: Thanks for feedback no usecase yet just evaluating how it works.